# AngularJS angular-drag-and-drop-lists move item

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm using this library: https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists with this particular example: http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested.

To move one item to another place I have `dnd-moved="list.splice($index, 1)"` but apart from this I need to have a `dnd-drop="onDrop(list, item, index)"` that I put directly on the `<ul>`. This function is empty but this overwrites the other one and I cannot move the item properly.

Answer (score 1):

I combined both:

```
dnd-moved="onDrop(list, item, $index)"

$scope.onDrop = function(list, item, index) {
        list.splice(index, 1);
      };
```